# Set value after True to True as well if another condition is meet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My Dataframe looks as follows (AboveOrEqual99result represent the state of the AboveOrEqual99 column after the operation afterwards):

| Index | Percentage | PercentageDiff | AboveOrEqual99 | AboveOrEqual99result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 0 | False | False |
| 2 | 100 | 50 | True | True |
| 3 | 99 | -1 | True | True |
| 4 | 98 | -1 | False | True |
| 5 | 99 | 1 | True | True |
| 6 | 50 | -49 | False | False |
| 7 | 99 | 49 | True | True |
| 8 | 98 | -1 | False | True |
| 9 | 97 | -1 | False | True |
| 10 | 96 | -1 | False | True |
| 11 | 50 | -46 | False | False |

Now I want to add those values to the `AboveOrEqual99%` Column which have a diff from 1 or below. Also note that this could happen more then once. So if there is a sequence of 99, 98, 97, 96 etc. all of this columns should be set to `True`.
Does anyone know how to do this? Preferably without a for loop as the data is quite big.

My best attempt was this but it misses the relation to the previous rows. (And therefore will include sequences like 24,25,25) which is not what I want.

```py
df["AboveOrEqual99"] = df["AboveOrEqual99"] | df["PercentageDiff"].abs()<=1
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use both conditions to set your value:

- PercentageDiff is 1 or less
- the previous AboveOrEqual99 is True

```
df.loc[df['PercentageDiff'].le(1)
     & df['AboveOrEqual99'].shift(), 'AboveOrEqual99'] = True
```

Comment: Hello, this only seems to work for the first value after the ``True`` value. So if I have a sequence of 99, 98, 98, 98 it only appears to change the ``True`` relative to the first 98, but not the other 2. Is there an elegant way to change all of those?
(Applying this function in a for loop as long as something changes should work but does not seem very elegant).

Comment: @Manuel, yes of course, I thought you wanted to limit to one. Can you provide a more generic example?

Comment: sorry for not being clear enoth I want all of these values to change to ``True``. I have updated the example in the question, I hope this makes it clear.